# What is the difference between transaction storage, vault, and ledger in Corda?

Tags: database, blockchain, corda

Recently, I started learning Corda and am a bit confused in the terminology. 
I know *transaction storage stores all the transactions of a node and vault is a table which stores only the relevant transactions*.

But what are those relevant transactions which are stored in vault? And what kind of transactions are not stored in vault but are there in transaction storage?

And also, how these different storage mechanisms implemented in real life scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

The vault doesn't store transactions. It stores the relevant *states* from any transactions the node records.

In general, a state is considered relevant if the node is one of the state's `participants`. However, there are two exceptions:

- States that extend `OwnableState` will only be stored if the node is the `owner`
- A node can choose to record every state in a transaction, instead of just the relevant ones, by setting the `statesToRecord` flag in `ReceiveTransactionFlow` to `ALL_VISIBLE`, as follows:

  ```
  ReceiveTransactionFlow(
      otherSideSession = otherSession,
      checkSufficientSignatures = true,
      statesToRecord = StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE)
  ```